# How MII register read errors are handled for 16bit phy registers?

Tags: drivers, network-interface

`phy_read` method in /include/linux/phy.h returns a 32 bit value. phy drivers uses this method for reading MII registers which are 16 bit. `phy_read` method returns a 32 bit value. storing a 16 bit value on a 32 bit field makes 0xFFFF as 0x0000FFFF, in 16 bit field that would have been considered as -1(error) and dealt that way, but storing that in 32 bit is making it a large positive value rather than a error. This changes the course of driver execution and creates changes link parameters in undesired manner.
I observed this for `genphy_read_status` method where value returned by `phy_read` is and int(4 bytes) however it contains 0xFFFF in case management lines are removed or some error occurs. Since returned value is 4 bytes all the checks that check whether it is smaller than zero fails. In such scenario link speed and duplicity is changed to maximum possible speed(that is 1000Mbps) even if it is not capable of that. 
So how phy driver handles such situation? Is it normal for link to change it's configuration in such manner if such hardware error occurs? Changing size of read to u16 from int might solve issue so why that is not done?
All these issues were observed in linux kernel 3.8.13. Latest linux source seems to be similar though I did not test error situation on that.